# Saving nxpd generated graph plots

Tags: python, networkx

The documentation on nxpd is very clear on how to print the graph internal to ipython, but how do you save the graph as a .png or .pdf? The method below reads in a dataframe (mc) containing the probability of state changes and an output path to save the plotted graph. It is unclear to me how to pass the nxpd draw to pyplot or use an internal save method.

NXPD documentation is limited: https://github.com/chebee7i/nxpd

```
def DrawMarkov(mc, outputPath):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import networkx as nx
    from nxpd import draw
    ## Draw as an internal to ipython
    # draw(G, show='ipynb')
    ## OR
    # from nxpd import nxpdParams
    # nxpdParams['show'] = 'ipynb' 

    def Add_Nodes(G, name):
        for node in range(0,len(mc) ):
    #         print(node); print(type(node)); print(color_map[node])
            G.add_node(node, style='filled', fillcolor=color_map[node], )

    def Add_Edges(G,mc):
        for start in range(0,len(mc[0])):
            # print(start,'\n')
            for finish in range(0,len(mc) ):
                # print(mc[start][finish])
                if mc[start][finish]!=0:
                    G.add_edge(start, finish, weight=mc[start][finish], label=str(mc[start][finish]) )

    color_map = {0: 'lightblue', 
                 1:'palegreen', 
                 2:'lightcoral'}

    ## Plot DiGraph
    G = nx.DiGraph()  
    Add_Nodes(G,mc)  
    Add_Edges(G,mc)  
    mapping={0:'State1', 1:'State2', 2:'State3'}
    G = nx.relabel_nodes(G,mapping)  

    ## Output  
    draw(G, layout='dot')  # , show='ipynb'  # unclear how to pass graph to plt
    # plt.savefig(os.path.join(outputPath, 'Graph.png') )
```

Comment: What happens if you simply do `plt.savefig('Graph.png')`?  Assuming it's like networkx, that should do it.

Comment: draw() produces a .png in a new preview window (I'm on a mac), if the show='ipynb' argument is not used. plt.savefig('graph.png') produces: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'savefig' ".

Comment: How would I suppress the opening of the .png file and force it to save?

Comment: The error `'str' object has no attribute 'savefig'` suggests that you haven't imported 'plt' correctly, because it seems to think 'plt' is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the save format in the draw function. Check the implementation https://github.com/chebee7i/nxpd/blob/master/nxpd/nx_pydot.py for details.

Usage:

```
draw(G, format ='pdf')
```

Supported formats include:

```
'canon', 'cmap', 'cmapx', 'cmapx_np', 'dia', 'dot',
'fig', 'gd', 'gd2', 'gif', 'hpgl', 'imap', 'imap_np',
'ismap', 'jpe', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'mif', 'mp', 'pcl', 'pdf',
'pic', 'plain', 'plain-ext', 'png', 'ps', 'ps2', 'svg',
'svgz', 'vml', 'vmlz', 'vrml', 'vtx', 'wbmp', 'xdot', 'xlib'
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17465409)

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist, I did include usage example in my answer. Thanks to whrrgarbl for the edit to make it clear.